# “Crime reducing” Vs. “Crime reduction”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, modifiers, attributive-nouns

> - 1) Capital punishment could be a crime **reduction** tool.
> - 2) Capital punishment could be a crime-**reducing** tool

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

In other words, can they be used interchangeably?

---

First sentence: Reduction is an attributive noun, which acts like a modifying noun for the word tool.

Second sentence is a hyphenated adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the point of view of the practical meaning, they are interchangeable. The difference is stylistic.